# Jquery height return false values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I'am serching solution in google. And saw some solutions to this but noone help me. When i asking in chrome about height(). It returns me true value, it's 1627. But when i write in script where it will be changed to this. It returns me 1290. And i don't know why. How can i return true height from document (because window can't help me). I'am trying with height(), innerHeight() and outerHeight().

Here is a screen with my problem: http://www.speedyshare.com/hTUDt/1.png

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = $("#menu").height();
    var content = $("body").outerHeight(true);

    if(menu != content)
    {
        menu = content;

        $("#menu").css({'height':menu+'px'});
    }
});
```

or like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var menu = $('#menu');

        $(window).resize(function () {
        var height = $('#body').height();
                menu.css({
                    'height': height +  'px', 
                });
        }).trigger('resize');
});
```

It's doesn't work.

In css i have :

```
 #menu {
width: 15%;
/*height: 100%;*/
background: #F5F5F5;
padding-top: 1%;
/* padding-bottom: 1%; */
font-size: 1.6rem;
font-family: 'Lato';
font-weight: 300;
color: #969696;
position: absolute;
border-right: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 1px #fff;
}
```

In firebug i see what's happend. He takes a height value 1290 (I don't know why) instead real height of body or 1626

Comment: try `$('your_selector').prop('clientHeight');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('element').css('height', 'auto !important')
```

Note: `auto` can be `100%` or a fixed number (i.e '1626px')